# Angular directives, use of replace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm going to explain an usual thing that i see when i'm doing an angular application. I usually made a lot of directives to module my view application, like in angular doc, i used to write my templates like this:

myDirective1:

```
<div class="myDiv">
  <span class="mySpan">Hello world!</span>
  <img src="hello.jpg">
</div>
```

and, normally in another directive i do:

```
<div data-my-directive1></div>
```

Well it causes that i add one element that is dispensable, right?, i can avoid one div, for sure angular directives has 'replace' attribute, i can do:

```
angular.module('myModule')
.directive('myDirective1', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'tmpl.html'
  };
});
```

But, if you use this method in "big" apps, how can replace method impacts in performance, i don't find any reference to this, i think that replace involves more DOM work than without replace, anybody knows if replace overmuch is not advisable? what do you think?

Comment: The cost will be trivial and might actually be less.  Angular builds the DOM from scratch so any difference in time will be a trivial difference.